# MissingReferenceException after scene reload

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I just want reload a scene after GameOver. I have searched on the net but it didn't give me a clear reason and solution. Can someone point me the list of reason for this. I have posted below code for my scene reload.

```
Time.timeScale = 1;
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

Then my code for GameManager

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Awake()
     {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
     DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
     }
}
```

Kindly inform me if you need additional info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi from what I saw on your code you might be missing some stuff on your sigleton code for the game manager, for example not having multiple instances for the game manager (each time you reload a scene you're making a new one and not destroying it on load).

withouth seeing all your scene I can't find out the why but I did some simple code to reload a scene and keep one scene manager only.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GMScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static GMScript instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null || instance == this)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

        Debug.Log("Scene reloaded");
    }

    public void ReloadScene()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            ReloadScene();
        }
    }

}
```

Also make sure the scene is added to project settings, I'm using space key for reloading but you can put out any method fits your needs.

Also make sure all your objects that will need access of the gamemanager update their reference once the scene loads(preferably on start method, as we use awake for the singleton handle), this can be done using a find method like GameObject.FindWithTag.

Comment: Tried this but still doesn't work. The error is pointing to other script which contain a list of gameobject. My code that causes error is is shapeSpawnerGO.GetComponent<ShapeSpawnerChild>().listofShape[rcv_ShapeIndex].activeSelf; this checks status of gameobject inside a list

Comment: Can you please make check if this vector "listofShape[rcv_ShapeIndex]" is not losing its data and the index "rcv_ShapeIndex" points to a filled position, once you make a reload on the scene before calling "activeSelf"

Comment: I've found the problem kindly look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem I have this code

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Awake()
     {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
     DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
     }

    void Start()
    {
        shapeSpawnerGO = GameObject.Find("SpawnShapesObj");
        scoreGO = GameObject.Find("ScoreText");
        lifeGo = GameObject.Find("LifeText");
    }
}
```

Then after reload scene the reference for this 3 becomes null it has something to do DontDestroyOnLoad(this); which means the GameManager script won't be destroyed after reload so when the game reloads the GameManager stays while it's reference get's destroyed. I'll check for efficient solution on this one